# How do I use Spark's registerDataFrameAsTable in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Having trouble with using `registerDataFrameAsTable`. Per the documentation, it looks to be within the `sqlContext` class, so I naturally tried this:

```
df = spark.registerDataFrameAsTable(mydf, "table1")
```

but that led to this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'registerDataFrameAsTable'
```

I tried this as well:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
df = SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(mydf, "table1")
```

but that led to this odd error:

TypeError: registerDataFrameAsTable() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tableName'

This seems to be the wrong way to use the function since it looks like I have to explicitly name the parameters, and it's also expecting the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest migrating your application to pyspark 2.x or if you learning start with 2.x. I provided the code for both 2.x and 1.x below.

**SPARK 2.X**

If you had a spark DataFrame `df`:

```python
df.show(5)
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|   _c5|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|  1|5.1|3.5|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  2|4.9|  3|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  3|4.7|3.2|1.3|0.2|setosa|
#|  4|4.6|3.1|1.5|0.2|setosa|
#|  5|  5|3.6|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

You could use [`createOrReplaceTempView`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView) to register this as a table:

```python
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
spark.sql("select * from people").show(n=5)
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|   _c5|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|  1|5.1|3.5|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  2|4.9|  3|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  3|4.7|3.2|1.3|0.2|setosa|
#|  4|4.6|3.1|1.5|0.2|setosa|
#|  5|  5|3.6|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

Alternatively, you could use [`createGlobalTempView`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createGlobalTempView):

```python
df.createGlobalTempView("people_global")
tempdf=spark.sql("select * from people_global")
tempdf.show(n=5)
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|   _c5|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
#|  1|5.1|3.5|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  2|4.9|  3|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#|  3|4.7|3.2|1.3|0.2|setosa|
#|  4|4.6|3.1|1.5|0.2|setosa|
#|  5|  5|3.6|1.4|0.2|setosa|
#+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

But this will throw `TempTableAlreadyExistsException` if the name already exists.

**SPARK 1.X**

You can use [`pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable):

```python
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize(
    [
        Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80),
        Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80),
        Row(name='Alice', age=10, height=80)
    ]
).toDF()
df.show()
#+---+------+-----+
#|age|height| name|
#+---+------+-----+
#|  5|    80|Alice|
#|  5|    80|Alice|
#| 10|    80|Alice|
#+---+------+-----+

sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "table1")
dftemp=sqlContext.sql("select * from table1")
dftemp.show()
#+---+------+-----+
#|age|height| name|
#+---+------+-----+
#|  5|    80|Alice|
#|  5|    80|Alice|
#| 10|    80|Alice|
#+---+------+-----+
```

Comment: Great work on editing my answer @pault. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm already on PySpark 2.3.0. Is `registerDataFrameAsTable` available only on Spark 1.x? I don't see that noted anywhere

Comment: I think its also available in the 2.x, as I mentioned please check the doc http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/spark-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-2017_12_08_16_02-e4639fa-docs/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: @simplycoding if you think my answer worked out for you, please upvote and if its the right solution tick the answer.